# How does a type become a function in Go?

Tags: go, syntax

I am looking at [some Kubernetes source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo_test.go#L31-L101).

I see this:

```
// GetByKey returns the key if it exists in the list returned by kl.
func (kl keyLookupFunc) GetByKey(key string) (interface{}, bool, error) {
    for _, v := range kl() {
        if v.name == key {
            return v, true, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, false, nil
}
```

I know hazily how to read this, but I'm sure I'm going to get my terminology wrong: There's a type somewhere called `keyLookupFunc`, and `kl` is effectively an instance of it, and this function, named `GetByKey` can be called on it.  It accepts a `key` whose type is `string`, and it returns three values, etc. etc.

(I don't see the BNF for this particular construction at [my best guess as to where it should live in the language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types), but I've seen this construction several times before so I take it on faith.)

Higher up in the source code, I notice this:

```
// keyLookupFunc adapts a raw function to be a KeyLookup.
type keyLookupFunc func() []testFifoObject
```

OK, so indeed `keyLookupFunc` is a type, and it is used to describe something that is a function that takes zero parameters and returns a slice of `testFifoObject`s.

So naïvely, if I have a `keyLookupFunc`-typed variable in my hand, I should be able to call `GetByKey` "on" it.  I am not entirely sure how a function can behave like a type in this situation, but I'll take it on faith.

Now when I look to see how this is all used, I [see this partial stuff](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo_test.go#L88-L103):

```
func TestDeltaFIFO_requeueOnPop(t *testing.T) {
    f := NewDeltaFIFO(testFifoObjectKeyFunc, nil, nil)

    f.Add(mkFifoObj("foo", 10))
    _, err := f.Pop(func(obj interface{}) error {
        if obj.(Deltas)[0].Object.(testFifoObject).name != "foo" {
            t.Fatalf("unexpected object: %#v", obj)
        }
        return ErrRequeue{Err: nil}
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("unexpected error: %v", err)
    }
    if _, ok, err := f.GetByKey("foo"); !ok || err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("object should have been requeued: %t %v", ok, err)
    }
```

Note the `f.GetByKey("foo")` invocation.  `f` is a pointer to a `DeltaFIFO`, which [I just happen to know is returned by `NewDeltaFIFO`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L51-L61).

Given that `f` is a pointer to a `DeltaFIFO`, how can it also be a `keyLookupFunc` such that this code can call `GetByKey` "on" it?  How do I connect these dots?

Comment: `DeltaFIFO` **is not also** `keyLookupFunc`, but **it also has a method** called `GetByKey` https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L392-L402. Two different types can have a method with the same name, no problem there.

Comment: Thank you; I should have seen that; how embarrassing.  That means, however, that this `GetByKey` function is not used in the rest of [this `.go` file](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go), right?

Comment: It seem like not, maybe it's legacy, maybe it's something intended for later use, I don't know. If you do [this search](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keyLookupFunc&type=) you can see that that identifier is only used in some 1 year old documentation... And if you do [this search](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=testFifoObject&type=) you'll see that there is no actual function that matches the `keyLookupFunc` type... By the way if you're interested in function types with methods, look into `net/http.HandlerFunc`, it's famous.

Comment: FWIW, a function isn't "behaving like a type". It's behaving like a value (which it is), that has a type (which every value does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the two`GetByKey` methods are two separate methods on two different types, (Two different types with a method with the same name):

Note the last `f.GetByKey` is:

```
// GetByKey returns the complete list of deltas for the requested item,
// setting exists=false if that list is empty.
// You should treat the items returned inside the deltas as immutable.
func (f *DeltaFIFO) GetByKey(key string) (item interface{}, exists bool, err error) {
    f.lock.RLock()
    defer f.lock.RUnlock()
    d, exists := f.items[key]
    if exists {
        // Copy item's slice so operations on this slice (delta
        // compression) won't interfere with the object we return.
        d = copyDeltas(d)
    }
    return d, exists, nil
}
```

and this called once here (in `delta_fifo.go` file at `return f.GetByKey(key)`):

```
// Get returns the complete list of deltas for the requested item,
// or sets exists=false.
// You should treat the items returned inside the deltas as immutable.
func (f *DeltaFIFO) Get(obj interface{}) (item interface{}, exists bool, err error) {
    key, err := f.KeyOf(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false, KeyError{obj, err}
    }
    return f.GetByKey(key)
}
```

And also called three times here (in `delta_fifo_test.go` file at `f.GetByKey("foo")`):

```
func TestDeltaFIFO_requeueOnPop(t *testing.T) {
    f := NewDeltaFIFO(testFifoObjectKeyFunc, nil, nil)

    f.Add(mkFifoObj("foo", 10))
    _, err := f.Pop(func(obj interface{}) error {
        if obj.(Deltas)[0].Object.(testFifoObject).name != "foo" {
            t.Fatalf("unexpected object: %#v", obj)
        }
        return ErrRequeue{Err: nil}
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("unexpected error: %v", err)
    }
    if _, ok, err := f.GetByKey("foo"); !ok || err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("object should have been requeued: %t %v", ok, err)
    }

    _, err = f.Pop(func(obj interface{}) error {
        if obj.(Deltas)[0].Object.(testFifoObject).name != "foo" {
            t.Fatalf("unexpected object: %#v", obj)
        }
        return ErrRequeue{Err: fmt.Errorf("test error")}
    })
    if err == nil || err.Error() != "test error" {
        t.Fatalf("unexpected error: %v", err)
    }
    if _, ok, err := f.GetByKey("foo"); !ok || err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("object should have been requeued: %t %v", ok, err)
    }

    _, err = f.Pop(func(obj interface{}) error {
        if obj.(Deltas)[0].Object.(testFifoObject).name != "foo" {
            t.Fatalf("unexpected object: %#v", obj)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("unexpected error: %v", err)
    }
    if _, ok, err := f.GetByKey("foo"); ok || err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("object should have been removed: %t %v", ok, err)
    }
}
```

---

And the other method is:

```
// GetByKey returns the key if it exists in the list returned by kl.
func (kl keyLookupFunc) GetByKey(key string) (interface{}, bool, error) {
    for _, v := range kl() {
        if v.name == key {
            return v, true, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, false, nil
}
```

and this is not used  (not called).

Comment: The 2nd part of your answer seems incorrect to me, [NewDeltaFIFO](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2986b37de06fcd1bf94e68b49b6c8d87c389d3c2/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L51) returns an instance of `*DeltaFIFO` and not of `keyLookupFunc`. To me it seems that `keyLookupFunc` and its method `GetByKey` aren't used anywhere. Unless, of course, I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your answer.  I tend to agree with @mkopriva; the three invocations you reference are exactly what I'm asking about.  I don't see how it is possible that the "target" of the `GetByKey` function invocation here could possibly be a `keyLookupFunc`, which would seem to be a requirement.

Comment: A.R's answer is correct.  The problem you are having is that you found a method called `GetByKey` on the `keyLookupFunc` type, but lots of `GetByKey` methods can exist with various receivers.  In fact, `DeltaFIFO` has its own `GetByKey` (which A.R references in the beginning) so nothing in the code originally posted is very calling the `GetByKey` with the `keyLookupFunc` receiver.

Comment: Ah, I see; yes, OK, I got his/her answer entirely backwards!  Now that I re-read it, I see he/she is saying that the `GetByKey` function callable on `keyLookupFunc` receivers is never used.  @A.R, I'll award you the answer.  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: @LairdNelson: And How does a type become a function in Go? [try this example](https://play.golang.org/p/-BGlRggOA7)

Comment: Thanks, @A.R; a lifetime ago I programmed Perl extensively and Go receivers remind me very much of the way that I recall that OO methods in Perl worked, where the fact that the "target" is effectively just another syntactically-assisted argument to the function. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Function is a first class citizen in Go: it can have a methods on it and even implement interfaces.

https://play.golang.org/p/d-N4OKLirQ